# Error when running mongodump

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have a rollback file, but when I run mongodump on it I get an error:

```
mongodump.exe .\test.foo.2016-04-27T16-49-54.0.bson > f.json
02:33.521+0100    positional arguments not allowed: [.\test.foo.2016-04-27T16-49-54.0.bson]
02:33.522+0100    try 'mongodump --help' for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

You just used the wrong command. You have to use the bsondump command instead of the mongodump command. Mongodump is only for create of the backup file. From the parameters you provide in your command I assume that you want to convert the bson file to a human-readable json file.

Comment: I'll give that a try!